# How to rotate YouTube embed in CSS3?

Tags: video, css

I have the following page where I try to rotate a YouTube video by 45 degrees.

http://development.zeta-two.com/development/backbone/video.html

I'm using the transform: rotate property.
The rotation works but the video isn't playing properly.
Is there any way to make this work?

EDIT: I'm testing this with Chrome 12.0.742.112.
The sound works but the video shows only a still frame every now and then.

Comment: please specify which browsers you're testing with.

Comment: Have you tried the HTML player instead of the Flash version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, using the new HTML5 compatible embed works fine.